# linux_binprm in execve()

Tags: c, linux, kernel

In the source execve() system call
http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=fs/exec.c#l186

There is a structure linux_binprm

could you please tell me the relevance of the structure.

Answer (score 3):

It encapsulates all the data needed to execute a program: it's virtual memory area, filename on disk, file descriptor table, whether it's a binary program or a script, etc. See its [definition at LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/include/linux/binfmts.h#L28).

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing, http://lxr.linux.no is your friend, see http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/include/linux/binfmts.h#L28

Comment: Alternate for the above link : http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/binfmts.h#L14

Comment: What is the full name of the abbreviation ```bprm```? My understanding is that ```b``` stands for binary, ```pr``` stands for program, then what does ```m``` mean? Or simply ```prm``` is program? (This [website](https://wenboshen.org/posts/2016-09-15-kernel-execve.html) contains a lot of ```bprm```)

Comment: @EthanL. bprm just stands for “binary program”.